# Problems using protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel and precompile with WPF client

Tags: wpf, wcf, performance, protobuf-net, precompile

Can anybody shed any light on how I can use the precompiled protobuf-net serializer assembly with WCF and a client (not to serialize/deserialize in code) to speed up first use of a DTO type?

I have managed to gain a lot of petrformance improvement in my large WCF/WPF application by using protobuf-net vs. datacontractserializer. However, even though I can precompile a serialization assembly from my DTO's, I cannot make WCF or it's WPF Client use it. The web service process always takes a long time for any first call from that process involving a new DTO, presumably to generate a serialization assembly on the fly.
How can I instruct the WCF server and/or the WPF client to use my generated assembly?

On a related issue, I have properties of type SolidColorBrush in some DTO's and this makes the precompiler fall over with "No serializer defined for type: System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush".
I have some code to add this support to the protobuf-net model, but I cannot understand how to apply it (to the precompiler or my code), when the rest of the DTO's are decorated with attibutes e.g. ProtoContractAttribute.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the only way to make WCF use a precompiled model would be configure WCF manually through code, in particular adding a `ProtoOperationBehavior` manually, and specifying the model:

```
var behavior = new ProtoOperationBehavior();
behavior.Model = new MyPrecompiledSerializer();
```

I confess I don't have a full end-to-end WCF example of doing that. I suspect it may be easier for me, in a new release, to tweak `ProtoBehaviorExtension` and/or `ProtoBehaviorAttribute` to allow you to specify the custom serializer-type via configuration - but that code does not exist today.

In the interim, if the issue is a slight delay on the first operation, then you can also add a few of the types you need *exlicitly* toe the default model, and compile it:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Foo), true);
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Bar), true);
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CompileInPlace();
```

that said: the compilation isn't horrendously slow - I'd be a little surprised if it is causing *noticeable* delay, unless your model is *really* complex (hundreds of types). Is it possible the delay is just WCF, network, TCP, etc overheads?

---

Regarding `SolidBrush`, and by implication: `Color` - it is possible to configure them *at runtime*:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(System.Windows.Media.Color), false)
    .Add("R", "G", "B", "A");
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush), false)
    .Add("Color");
```

However, I have not yet added a mechanism to do this when using "precompile" - it is much trickier at the technical level: I can't just use an executable method on (say) an attribute, because the assembly being inspected by "precompile" could be for any CLI (Silverlight, WinRT, .NET 1.1, CF, etc) - and as such, it is loaded by very different mechanisms.

My preferred approach would be: don't expose it as `System.Windows.Media.Color` - write your own DTO class that represents the *data* (rather than the final implementation), and map between them. Alternatively, it is also possible to write your own utility console exe that acts like "precompile", by configuring the model then calling `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Compile(string,string)` or `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Compile(CompilerOptions)`.

Comment: Marc, thanks for your help. I am trying to test out and implement the suggestions that you made. I particularly like the idea of CompileInPlace and, yes, I have hundreds of DTO's. I will follow up here when I have tried it all out.

Comment: Marc, I have had some great success with r580 and pre-compiling, however I have just installed r602 and I now have a problem. I use ImplicitFields.AllFields to get my DTO's to work with the minmimum extra code and precompile ran ok, now I get "Non-public member cannot be used with full dll compilation" on any private declaration. Any ideas? Thanks